# Experimental design and econometrics distinction: random effects and degrees of freedom

Tags: econometrics, experiment-design, random-effects-model

Consider the model used in experimental design:

$$Y_{ij}=\mu+r_i+\epsilon_{ij}$$

Where, $r_i$ is drawn from a population at random and follows a normal distribution. Let's say $i=1,...,k$.

My notes state that the degrees of freedoms for the $r_i$ are the same as for the corresponding fixed effects model, ie. $k-1$.

I am confused as in econometrics the random effect model reduces the degrees of freedom, after all the mean of $r_i$ is already estimated so only the variance needs to be estimated, so the $df$ should be 1. The econometrics model looks the same as the one above (apart from also having a slope). Why are the degrees of freedom asserted to be different?

It's stated that random effects model should be used if the variable is random, and fixed effects if the variable is fixed. However, in econometrics random effects models and fixed effects models are both used on any data without such concerns. Are the random effects in experimental design and econometrics referring to at all the same thing?